# How to wget a single page with NO assets ONLY the HTML page

Tags: wget

Can someone give me the wget command to download a single html page without any assets. Literally only the html page, and nothing else. Example:

wget --no-check-certificate --level=0 https://blablabla.com/get?id=1111

result: 1111.html

Comment: It already downloads only a single page, unless instructed otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

[`wget` man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html) states that

```
--level=depth
           Set the maximum number of subdirectories that Wget will
           recurse into to depth.  In order to prevent one from
           accidentally downloading very large websites when using
           recursion this is limited to a depth of 5 by default, i.e.,
           it will traverse at most 5 directories deep starting from the
           provided URL.  Set -l 0 or -l inf for infinite recursion
           depth.

                   wget -r -l 0 http://<site>/1.html

           Ideally, one would expect this to download just 1.html.  but
           unfortunately this is not the case, because -l 0 is
           equivalent to -l inf---that is, infinite recursion.  To
           download a single HTML page (or a handful of them), specify
           them all on the command line and leave away -r and -l.(...)
```

So `--level=0` does mean infinite recursion, you should not provide any `--level` if you want to download single file. Taking this into account your command should be altered to

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://blablabla.com/get?id=1111
```